# Number of circles required to reach a length of 100 million units in form of circle

Tags: number-theory

I need a formula to find out number of circles required to reach a length of 100 million units in form of circle. All circles are in offset from first circle with +1 unit in radius. all circles have a common centre.

N=X*3.14*2 (x is the value of radius of circle)(N=perimeter of circle)

Y=N+6.28 ((Y is the value of circumference of next circle's radius with x+1unit) (a circle with a radius of 100 units has a perimeter of 628 units, 
a circle with 101 unit has a perimeter of 634.28 units, a circle with 102 unit has a perimeter of 640.56 units, the difference is always 6.28 units.))

so, addition of perimeter of first three circles is (628+634.28+640.56) 1902.84) units. what should be the formula to find out number of circles required to reach 100 million units.

Comment: If all the circles have a common center, then how can they be offset from the first circle, or reach much of any length at all?

Comment: @GerryMyerson the circles are in radiating pattern, like first circle is of radius 100mm, the second circle is of radius 101mm and expanding.

Comment: N= 100x3.14x2=628, N1=101x3.14x2=634.28, N2=102x3.14x2=640.56, N3=103x3.14x2=646.84, N4=104x3.14x2=653.12 and so on.....

Comment: I would recommend clarifying the question and making the terms consistent. It's a bit vague to say "circle that reaches $10^{8}$ units" - so what exactly reaches the value of $10^8$? The perimeter? or the radius? Also, if you want a circle with perimeter $10^8$, it's possible to simply solve for the radius and you're done.

Comment: Hello @MattiP. the need is to find total number of circles required to reach a value of 100 million units (units along the perimeter) when every circles is expanding with +1 units from the preceding circle. the first circle radius is 100 units so perimeter is 628 units the second circle radius is 101 units (with common center) so perimeter is 634.28 units. i have to add perimeter of every circle to reach 100 million units.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear! When you consider the sum of perimeters, it's an arithmetic sequence. Can you write an expression for, firstly, the perimeter of the $n$th circle; and, secondly, the sum of the first $n$ circles?

Comment: @MattiP. your explanation is helping a lot... The expression for perimeter of nth circle would be: 100000000= (r)*3.14*2. but i cant write expression for 'the sum of first n circles'. kindly help

Comment: @MattiP. is this equation going to help?   100000000=100+(n-1)*6.28 (where n is number of circles)

Comment: Read the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: @MattiP. I'm not a student of mathematics, i design shelters. if you can help me with an equation for my problem that would be of a great help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We consider $n$ circles, where the radius of each circle is equal to $99+n$. The perimeter of the $n$th circle is therefore
$$
p(n) = 2\pi (99+n)
$$
When we add up the perimeters of the circles, we get the sum of an arithmetic progression
$$
\begin{split}
S =& p(1) + p(2) +p(3) +\ldots + p(n)\\ =& 2\pi \left(100+101+102 + \ldots + 99 +n \right)\\
=&2\pi(\underbrace{99+99+99 +\ldots+99}_{\text{n terms}}) + 2\pi \left(1+2+3+\ldots+n \right)
\end{split}
$$
The summing the $99$'s together makes just $99n$, and for the sum $1+2+\dots+n$ we can find the identity
$$
1+2+3+\ldots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
and therefore
$$
S = 198\pi n + 2\pi \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
We want this to be at least $S= 10^8$, and therefore we get the equation
$$
2\times 10^8 = 396\pi n + 2\pi n^2 + 2\pi n \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 2\pi n^2 + 398\pi n - 2\times 10^8 = 0
$$
Numerically, we can find $n\approx 5~544$. This is the number of circles required so that the sum of perimeters is at least to 100 million.

Comment: So the answer is 5544 circles. Many many thanks @Matti P.

Comment: You're welcome! If you think that the answer is correct, feel free to mark is as the accepted answer.